# Super-pinging users by site account number creates duplicate users, causes confusion and gnashing of teeth

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat, user-accounts, super-ping

It's really convenient to use the moderator-ping (`@@<userid>@<sitename>stackexchange.com`) to summon users into a chat room.

Unfortunately, this tends to create duplicate chat users if they happen to have an existing chat account associated with another site. Which is a problem if the existing user has access to rooms the new one does not. Or a really clever status text. Or a coveted low-digit ID number.

Sure, I could just *look for the user* on chat first; but if they have a different user name on their preferred site, that's difficult... and worse yet, it's inconvenient!

I would much prefer it if the system could simply do this for me. Or failing that, provide some convenient way to merge users.

Comment: Oh wow, this post made me realize that I've somehow ended up with two chat clones. That's rather uncool.

Comment: @Tim You should see the number of rcherns we currently have on chat.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Based on my own doppelganger, there also seems to be a second source of duplicates: comment threads being automatically moved to chat. My clone is listed as having 6 messages and 1 room - 6 messages which I never posted in 1 room which I never visited.

Comment: Yes; something is hokey here. I am attempting to de-hokey it.

Comment: De-hokey caused a brokey...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We couldn't decide how best to suppress an attack of the clones... it was a choice between Rick Deckard, and *the phantom menace* (which undermined an entire *franchise*).

In the end, due to moral and ethical concerns, we concluded that our successful experiment into cloning had to come to an end, so we are no longer involved in creating clone armies.

Comment: Decloning caused me some interesting problems - I was getting a denied message when trying to access Teacher's. Luckily @PaŭloEbermann explained the solution was to change my primary site in chat back to security.se as it had been changed to SO (where I am not a mod)