# Is there a way to find a list of top users by accumulated reputation scores across all Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion

I know that there's a way to list total user reputation on the Area51 site, but only among people committed to a particular Stack Exchange Network

Comment: For just the trilogy, there's the [Stackathlon](http://stackapps.com/questions/885/stackathlon-users-active-on-all-three-of-so-sf-and-su).

Answer (score 4):

You can use [the list of chat users](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users?tab=all&sort=reputation).  (I'm 117th or so*! I feel special.)

There are 25130 Area51 users and 22529 chat users* at the time of posting.  Most of these high-rep users you're looking for will have used one or both, I'm sure, since they're obviously dedicated to and informed about the network.

<sub>* Some of the chat users are dupes.</sub>

Comment: Do you know why some users are listed twice in the link?

Comment: @Siva There have been some bugs resulting in duplicate chat users, see  [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104918/super-pinging-users-by-site-account-number-creates-duplicate-users-causes-confus) for example.

Answer (score 1):

Following link provides the list of all top users across different SE sites.

[Top users in each SE site](https://stackexchange.com/leagues)

You still have to tabulate their reputation points to find the leader of all. Currently, the clear leader is [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Thanks for the link. But it only lists their reputations specific to each site (not across all sites)

Comment: As far as I know, I don't think there is a way for what you are trying to find out because the data for each site is hosted separately. Each user will have a different user id on different sites. I think Jon Skeet will still come on top.

Comment: @Siva If you only consider people who have linked their accounts then it shouldn't be too hard. Just depends on what data is public, although one could build a scraper.

Comment: @Matthew: Yes, that could be possible. That's why I mentioned `as far as I know` and I know very little. :-)